# How do I create a rest API to read a text or any file in go lang using gRPC?

Tags: api, go, grpc

I am trying to create a REST API in go programming language, to read the text file.

I want to build it using gRPC.

Answer (score 0):

You could follow the [Go introduction](https://grpc.io/docs/tutorials/basic/go.html) that's in the gRPC docs.

The basic process is as follows:

1) Write the Protocol Buffers definitions for your data structures and a gRPC service definition that integrates them:

```
package fileserver

message FileRequest {
  string name = 1;
}

message FileResponse {
  bytes contents = 1;
}

service FileServer {
  rpc ReadFile (FileRequest) returns (FileResponse) {}
}
```

2) Generate the gRPC/PB bindings using the "protoc" tool (you will need "protoc-gen-go" as well). The command is usually:

```
protoc --go_out=plugins=grpc:. *.proto
```

3) Implement the server:

```
type FileServer struct{}

func (s *FileServer) Dispatch(ctx context.Context, fileRequest *fileserver.FileRequest) (*fileserver.FileResponse, error) {
  f, _ := ioutil.ReadFile(fileRequest.Name)
  fileResponse := &fileserver.FileResponse{Contents: f}
  return fileResponse, nil
}
```